# Get the column that the cursor is on in vimscript

Tags: vimscript

In vimscript, how can I get the column that the cursor is currently on? I would like to save this value in a variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've got `col('.')` and `virtcol('.')`.

- The first one is to be used most of the time. It doesn't return the actual column number, but the byte index the cursor is on in the current line.
- The second one returns the actual column number

The tricky part is that sometimes a tab (1 byte) expand up to `&ts` columns, and a multibyte character have more than 1 byte that expand over only one column.

You'll need to read their documentation to know what you exactly need depending on what you do with that number after.

Comment: so to get the column of the cursor, the commands would be `col(".")` and `virtcol(".")`

Comment: Additionally, the commands `getpos(".")` and `getcurpos()` return a list of position values, with the 3rd element being column

Comment: Would you mind modifying your answer to be `col(".")` and `virtcol(".")`? Then I will accept it.

Comment: Of course. Done.

Comment: But how to get the column offset to the left border of the current window?

Comment: @job_start I'm not sure what you are after. `col()`  and `virtcol()` mostly relate to text within a buffer. If you are interested in width of windows you'll need other functions.